# Sending ID3D11Texture2D from C++ into C# UWP MediaPlayer

Tags: c#, c++, uwp, mpeg-dash, direct3d11

I've got a C++ unmanaged DLL that is basically a video playback engine. It streams video using the WMF and draws frames using TransferVideoFrame to a ID3D11Texture2D.

That's all working fine.

However, I've been tasked with implementing MPEG_DASH stream switching, and so I'm creating a C# wrapper that uses the MediaPlayer and the AdaptiveStreaming classes, to get DASH and HLS streaming working.

What I'm trying to figure out is, how do I send the frame pixel data from the MediaPlayer, into the C++ DLL to draw it to the ID3DTexture2D.

In C++, I have a function that returns a pointer to the ID3D11Texture2D,

```
ID3D11Texture2D* VideoPlayer::GetVideoTextureSurface()
{
    if (_ctxt.m_spVideoTexSRV) // ComPtr<ID3D11ShaderResourceView>
    {
        return _ctxt.m_spVideoTex.Get(); // ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D>
    }
    else return nullptr;
}
```

which I call from C# and get as an IntPtr.

```
[DllImport("VideoPlayer")]
private static extern IntPtr GetVideoTextureSurface();
```

And in C# the MediaPlayer has a method:

```
MediaPlayer.CopyFrameToVideoSurface(IDirect3DSurface destination)
```

Which I want to use to make MediaPlayer draw its frame into the C++ ID3D11Texture3D. But I am not sure how to pass an IntPtr into that. I'm trying to avoid copying frame buffers multiple times by drawing straight to the Texture.

I'm not even sure if this is the best approach. I could use MediaPlayer directly from C++, but I'm not even sure how to instantiate it. In C# it's simply:

```
MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
```

But when I try to create it in C++, I get the error, "Incomplete Type is not allowed".  Any ideas, insight or help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with the `DllImport`.

```
[DllImport("VideoPlayer")]
private static extern IntPtr GetVideoTextureSurface();
```

You need to marshall the returned pointer to ID3D11Texture2D type of struct. Please have look at the layout of the struct [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476635(v=vs.85).aspx). When you search for the underlying texture resource type, you will end up [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476521(v=vs.85).aspx). So it is a pointer to a `D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC` structure that describes a 2D texture resource.

```
typedef struct D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC {
  UINT             Width;
  UINT             Height;
  UINT             MipLevels;
  UINT             ArraySize;
  DXGI_FORMAT      Format;
  DXGI_SAMPLE_DESC SampleDesc;
  D3D11_USAGE      Usage;
  UINT             BindFlags;
  UINT             CPUAccessFlags;
  UINT             MiscFlags;
} D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC;
```

Lets define our own managed Struct

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MyStruct : IDirect3DSurface {
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public int MipLevels { get; set; }
    public uint ArraySize { get; set; }
    public DirectXPixelFormat Format { get; set; }
    public Direct3DMultisampleDescription SampleDesc { get; set; }
    public Direct3DUsage Usage { get; set; }
    public uint BindFlags { get; set; }
    public uint CPUAccessFlags { get; set; }
    public uint MiscFlags { get; set; }

    #region I Do not know about this part
    public Action Disposer { get; set; }
    public void Dispose() {
        Disposer();
    }
    #endregion I Do not know about this part

    public Direct3DSurfaceDescription Description => new Direct3DSurfaceDescription {
        Format = Format,
        Height = Height,
        Width = Width,
        MultisampleDescription = SampleDesc
    };
}
```

Here is a simple wrapper from native to managed struct:

```
public static MyStruct TestWrapper() {
        var ptr = GetVideoTextureSurface();
        var myStruct = Marshal.PtrToStructure<MyStruct>(ptr);
        myStruct.Disposer = () => Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
        return myStruct;
    }
```

Now you can use

```
MediaPlayer.CopyFrameToVideoSurface(myStruct);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I will give this a try!

Comment: @GlenRhodes, I am also curios to see if it works :) Let me know of the results, and if it solves the problem do not forget to check as answered so other people can see